# In HTML can I disable user interaction with an entire DOM sub-tree?

Tags: html

In HTML can I disable user interaction with an entire DOM sub-tree via CSS?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use CSS `pointer-events` property on an element to disable user interaction on it and its descendants.

```
div.disabled { pointer-events: none; }
```

You could also use the `user-select` property to further restrict the user interaction of text selection.

```
div.disabled { user-select: none; }
```

Note that the `user-select` property may need vendor prefixes.

---

However, these CSS properties will not disable keyboard interactions which could happen by way of tabbing into the descendants.

As per this reference -- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#inert-subtrees; there is a proposal of an `inert` property but it is not yet implemented by browsers.

So, as of now you will resort to Javascript to disable keyboard interactions. Just wire up the `keydown` event with `capture` and set the `returnValue` to `false`. Do not forget to allow <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to allow for an escape out, otherwise the focus could get trapped.

```
var noInteracts = document.getElementsByClassName('disabled');
[].map.call(noInteracts, function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 9) {       // allow tab key to escape out
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }, true);
});
```

You could also hide the highlight-outline on focus of inputs by this CSS:

```
div.disabled *:focus { outline: 0; }
```

Below is a demo with all of the above techniques combined.

**Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/hpowhh5c/5/**

**Snippet**:

```js
var noInteracts = document.getElementsByClassName('disabled');
[].map.call(noInteracts, function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 9) {
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
    }, true);
});
```

```css
div.disabled { 
    pointer-events: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; 
  user-select: none;
}
div.disabled *:focus { outline: 0; }
```

```html
<p>This is normal</p>
<form>
    <label>Input 1: <input id="i1" /> </label>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<hr />
<div class="disabled">
    <p>User interaction is disbled here</p>
    <form>
        <label>Input 2: <input id="i2" /> </label>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @BenAston: I have updated the answer to include a simple Javascript snippet to disable keyboard interaction as well. Hope that helps too.

Comment: This is not working for me, I am not using Mouse. but just the Keyboard

Comment: Gosh, looked up `inert` as it has been a while since you mentioned that, zero un-flagged browser support. Shame, that.

Comment: It seems like browser vendors are slowly starting to release un-flagged support for the `inert` attribute. At the time of writing [Safari is the only one with unflagged support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlelement_inert), but Chrome and Firefox are soon to follow.

Comment: Seems to be available in stable on all major browsers now except Firefox

Answer (score 1):

If you need to disable all types of interaction across the whole page, you can simply put a transparent `div` over everything:

```css
#mask {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10; /* some high z-index */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  user-select: none; /* prevents double clicking from highlighting entire page */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text">
  <button>button</button>
  <a href="https://google.com">link</a>

  <div id="mask"></div>
</body>

</html>
```