# Turn off user interaction with a WebView in a UWP form

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I am using a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView to view some web content. I would like to turn off all user interaction with the component. No keyboard events, no mouse events. How can I achieve this?

I have tried with cancelling the GettingFocus event, but my test-javascript running inside the webview still receive mouse clicks.

Here is a slightly modified version of the code I have tested with. daWebView is a WebView component.

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
      this.InitializeComponent();

      this.RequiresPointer = RequiresPointer.Never;
      Application.Current.RequiresPointerMode = ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested;

      bool res = daWebView.Focus(FocusState.Unfocused);

      daWebView.GettingFocus += DaWebView_GettingFocus;
      daWebView.PointerMoved += DaWebView_PointerMoved;

      Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///index.html");
      daWebView.Source = uri;
    }

    private void DaWebView_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // never happens.
      Debug.WriteLine("pointer moved");
    }

    private void DaWebView_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
    {
      // not working, it still gets focus and receive mouse movement.
      args.Cancel = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In HTML can I disable user interaction with an entire DOM sub-tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264310/in-html-can-i-disable-user-interaction-with-an-entire-dom-sub-tree)

Comment: Nico, thanks for the link. Sad to say no, I need to tell the component not to listen for the events. At least I need to be able to intercept them and control them. The WebView component seems too much like a cut-and-paste browser-in-a-frame to me.. I am trying to replace cefsharp, which is a good piece of software, except it's not working good in uwp.

Comment: Pavel, please see my updated question.

Comment: @Snorvarg, There no such api could disable interaction with WebView directly, the better way is disable `WebView` content with js injectio.

Comment: Yes, js injection seem to be the way to go. Thank you Nico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Turn off user interaction with a WebView in a UWP form

There no such api could disable interaction with WebView directly, the better way is disable WebView content with js injection. You could use [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync) method to inject js method to disable interaction. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view#interacting-with-web-view-content).

Comment: Yep, that is what I have found out too. It's a bit lazy of Microsoft to not expose the inner workings of the webview properly..