# Prevent child elements from being interactive and focusable

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm building an interactive widget that consists in making a button list out of a list of HTML markups. To achieve that, the HTML markup is wrapped with a button-like component `<div role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Action...">`. When clicking on the button, some script is executed.

I don't have control over that child HTML markup, and I want to prevent all other interactive elements from being interacted with. They should stay visible, though.

From the point of view of a mouse user, this can be achieved by setting `pointer-events: none;` on all child elements.

From the point of view of a keyboard user, I need a way to prevent interactive elements from being interacted with.

In this example, the focus should go from the first div with tabindex="0" to the second div with tabindex="0", without focusing on the `<a>` tag.

```css
.focusable {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.focusable > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.focusable:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div role="button" tabindex="0" class="focusable" aria-label="Action 0">
  <div>Some html markup
    <a href="#">Should not be focusable, but should be visible</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div role="button" tabindex="0" class="focusable" aria-label="Action 1">
  <div>Some html markup
    <input type="text" placeholder="should not be focusable" />
  </div>
</div>
```

One way I thought of achieving that is to set `tabindex="-1"` on the child interactive elements. It will remove those from the tab order. However, it will not prevent them from being accessed programmatically, for example, from a screen reader links menu.

I wondered if there are other techniques to make all child elements of an element non-interactive. Especially something that can be applied on a wrapper, so there is no need to find all interactive elements and replace them.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-disabled ..?

Comment: thanks! the doc says it can be used on a wrapper in order to disable the focus of the child elements, however when I test applying `aria-disabled="true"` to the parent div or to the anchor itself, it is still in the tab order and accessible using assistive technology

Comment: The docs says: "_the aria-disabled="true" only semantically exposes these elements as being disabled. Web developers must manually ensure such elements have their functionality suppressed when they are exposed in the disabled state._" Then there's also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden

Comment: It looks like a combination of `aria-hidden` (hides from accessibility tree) and `tabindex=0` (removes from tab navigation) would achieve the intended outcome. Though ideally I would love a solution where the markup can be added on a wrapper on not on each child element

Comment: I’m puzzled about your examples. You *cannot have interactive elements inside a button*! They will automatically become meaningless content, [presentational children](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#childrenArePresentational)
What I believe you want to do is to entirely hide anything outside something like a dialog, so establish a modal pattern? This could be done by adding a wrapper that has `aria-hidden"true"` and [`inert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert). Does that look helpful to you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In HTML can I disable user interaction with an entire DOM sub-tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264310/in-html-can-i-disable-user-interaction-with-an-entire-dom-sub-tree)

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. I cannot have interactive elements inside a button, that's why I am looking for preventing child elements from being interactive and focusable. `inert` is exactly what I would be looking for, if it had better support. I am not trying to do something like a modal. Imagine it more like a button that wraps an image, except that the image is not an <img> tag, but made of HTML elements. It looks like the best solution is to find all interactive child elements and apply both `aria-hidden` and `tabindex="-1"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution is to give [inert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert) attribute to the first child element of the `<div role="button">`. According to MDN:

> Specifically, inert does the following:
>
> - Prevents the click event from being fired when the user clicks on the element.
> - Prevents the focus event from being raised by preventing the element from gaining focus.
> - Hides the element and its content from assistive technologies by excluding them from the accessibility tree.

However browser support is not good, for example no support on Firefox.

For better compatibility the solution is to use:

- [`aria-hidden="true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden): hides from accessibility tree
- [`tabindex="-1"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex): removes from tab navigation
- [`pointer-events: 'none'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events): prevents pointer interaction

Comment: [Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert#browser_compatibility) for `inert` is now pretty good, including Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, you would need to assign the following:

```
<button aria-label="Label text … additional text">
  <div inert>
    …
    <a tabindex="-1"
       aria-hidden="true"
       style="pointer-events: none">
    …
```

Regarding the ARIA standard, part of this is already recommended standard behavior of button children. For [the button role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#button), it reads:

> Children Presentational:  True

Some roles have [presentational children](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#childrenArePresentational). That is to say, they should remove any roles from their children. Hence a link would not be exposed in the link menu.

> The DOM descendants are presentational. User agents SHOULD NOT expose descendants of this element through the platform accessibility API.

Unfortunately, it’s not a MUST and not implemented in browsers. So you’d need to implement that part manually.

### Hiding specific roles from the screen reader menus

Usually, you’d be adding `role="presentation"` or `role="none"` to the children so that they are not presented in the generated menus anymore.

Unfortunately, this does not work if applied by a script. A link will stay exposed as a link.

What works is to hide the element entirely through `aria-hidden`. This will also remove it from the accessible name calculation.

### Provide an accessible name for the button

Usually, the button’s name would be calculated from the texts of all children. Once you hide them all, the button is empty.

So you need to provide a name yourself with `aria-label`. Beware of [Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html), though.

Many screen reader users are sighted, and to direct voice control software towards a button, the visible text needs to match at least partially with the accessible name. So the `aria-label` value should start with the visible text. You could, for example, provide a backdrop that renders the original contents blurry and adds that label.

### Prevent user interaction

The above will not prevent user interaction directly with the children. [The `inert` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert) on a wrapper does that, but it’s not supported everywhere yet.

> […it] makes the browser "ignore" user input events for the element, including focus events and events from assistive technologies. […]

So you can also apply `tabindex="-1"` as you suggested, to make sure browsers that don’t support inert don’t allow keyboard interaction.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button *').forEach(n => {
  n.setAttribute('inert', '');
  n.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
  n.setAttribute('aria-hidden', '')
});
```

```css
button * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button>
  This should not be <a href="#" onclick="alert('damn, it‘s still a link')">a link</a>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. With `role="none"` and `role="presentation"`, the anchor is still accessible from links menu on VoiceOver. Only with `aria-hidden` it is not

Comment: That sux. It’s a bug and should be fixed in VoiceOver. `aria-hidden` will remove the content from the button’s accessible name calculation. Also, it would add a difference between what you can see and what is announced, which is not great for sighted screen reader users.

Comment: Also Firefox with NVDA has this issue if the role is changed by a script. If it’s present initially, there’s no issue.

Comment: Good context. I do want the content to be removed from the accessible name calculation, so `aria-hidden` works here. Sighted users including sighted screen reader users would understand the button purpose without reading the content of the interactive elements within it. Doing so could make the button name very long and not explicit

Comment: That’s ok, I’m just mentioning it for others.

Answer (score 0):

Adding tabindex="-1" and aria-hidden="true" should be good enough as  element is not conveying anything extra to the screen reader users.