# How to set all child elements of a div to read-only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that has a lot of child elements. I want this complete div and all the elements in this div to be uneditable. How do I set all the child elements to readonly? This div has a lot going on inside with a lot of dynamically changing child elements and I cannot traverse through all the elements to set them readonly. How can I set this complete div to readonly in an easy way? If i just set the parent div element to read only, will all the child elements automatically become readonly?

Some additional context: Why am I doing this? There is some text field somewhere inside this div that is causing the keyboard to popup on mobile. I want to fix this- and given that my entire web app is designed to be uneditable- i want to just set the whole thing to readonly to avoid any keyboard ever popping up.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571705/prevent-child-elements-from-being-interactive-and-focusable/74599481#74599481

Comment: What about users being able to copy and paste *from* your site/app? UI hint: don't take away copy & paste. Also, is it just the keyboard that you want to prevent from appearing, or are there other ways in which people are "editing" your site/app?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `readonly` attribute on all `input` and `textarea` inside your wrapper. This would still allow to focus these elements, but not to input values, so no on-screen keyboard should be produced.

If the keyboard pops up due to an [`autofocus` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus), or a script that’s executed earlier, changing the input to `readonly` *after* it already received focus might not help for your symptom. In that case, you could check for focus, and focus elsewhere as a reaction to close the keyboard again.

```js
const w = document.getElementById("wrapper");

w.querySelectorAll("input, textarea").forEach(i => i.setAttribute("readonly", ""));

// set focus on wrapper if its inside the wrapper, to reset any already open on-screen keyboard
if (w.contains(document.activeElement)) {
  w.focus();
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" tabindex="-1">
  <form>
    <p>
      <label>Text input
  <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum">
  </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Email input
  <input type="email" value="test@example.com" autofocus>
  </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Select input
  <select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option selected>Option 2</option>
  </select>
  </label>
    </p>
    <p><a href="#">A link</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: would `w.querySelectorAll("input, textarea")` also select <div role="input"> elements?

Comment: No it wouldn’t. It’s the [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors), which selects elements by node name. You could add an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like `[role="textbox"]`, but entirely custom inputs are difficult to handle. You’d need to apply `aria-readonly` on those to expose the readonly state to assistive technology. Whether the script will ignore any user input on it is entirely up to the script. That’s why I suggested the focus-fallback for `document.activeElement`.

Answer (score -1):

I think `user-select: none;` is what you're looking for. The text is unselectable while still allowing pointer events, unlike `pointer-events: none;`:

```css
p {
  user-select: none;
}

p:hover {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nulla risus, eleifend a dolor eu, rutrum sagittis ex. Donec sit amet odio sollicitudin, dictum lectus vel, pretium ipsum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
    posuere cubilia curae; Nam volutpat sodales ornare. Sed elementum dapibus neque a varius. Quisque ultrices imperdiet ante, quis posuere leo mattis eu. Ut sollicitudin turpis non urna tempor volutpat. Nam sed lorem a risus consectetur aliquet. Cras
    non erat semper, molestie dui id, pharetra metus. Aenean aliquet tortor sapien, non efficitur libero suscipit non. Phasellus condimentum, justo vel pulvinar maximus, mauris ipsum aliquet enim, vitae porttitor orci massa sit amet eros. Nulla ultrices
    purus sed nibh fringilla, sit amet ultrices justo malesuada. Donec accumsan vel ante ut sollicitudin. Nulla faucibus ante quis sem vestibulum, vitae gravida tortor lobortis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is still ignoring any input devices other than pointer devices. for example keyboard.